# signal.butter bandpass error: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1

Tags: python, scipy, bandpass-filter

I have been trying to use scipy's butter function and it has been working fine when I am trying to get the lowpass coefficients:

```
from scipy import signal
[b, a] = signal.butter(10, 0.3)
```

I strictly want to create a bandpass for 0.5Hz - 5Hz, but when I try to get the bandpass coefficients in the following code it gives me an error: `ValueError: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1`

```
from scipy import signal

[b, a] = signal.butter(2, [0.5,5], btype='bandpass')
```

I did find the following stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145529/band-pass-filter-valueerror-digital-filter-critical-frequencies-must-be-0-wn), but I am still unsure about the issue and I followed the requirements for using the signal.butter function from the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, for a digital filter, the values given for `Wn` must be expressed as fractions of the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), which is half the samping rate.  Either scale the values yourself, or specify the sample rate by also giving the `fs` argument, as in the following example

```
In [36]: from scipy import signal

In [37]: order = 2

In [38]: fs = 128.0  # Sample rate, in Hz                                             

In [39]: Wn = [0.5, 5.0]  # Filter cutoff frequencies, in Hz                                      

In [40]: b, a = signal.butter(order, Wn, btype='bandpass', fs=fs)                                     

In [41]: b                                                                                                           
Out[41]: array([ 0.01051921,  0.        , -0.02103843,  0.        ,  0.01051921])

In [42]: a                                                                                                           
Out[42]: array([ 1.        , -3.67848002,  5.09032297, -3.14352142,  0.73170972])
```